# css to remove text shadow on select / highlight text (mozilla)

Tags: css-selectors, selection, css

I'm using text shadows for most text site wide, but when you highlight / select the text - the text looks fuzzy. So in order to remove the text shadow I use this css from [here](http://www.welcomebrand.co.uk/thoughts/using-text-shadow-dont-forget-highlighting/).

```
::-moz-selection,
::-webkit-selection,
::selection {
    text-shadow: none;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
}
```

The problem is that for some reason `moz-selection` doesn't seem to work (anymore?) in mozilla (Firefox).

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/GMuzV/5/)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It seems like the problem was due to grouping multiple css rules (for the vendor specific css) together in conjuntion with the ::selection pseudo element.

I originally thought that it was sufficient to write each statement on a separate line.

I was mistaken.

So if I replace this code:

```
::-moz-selection,
::selection {
    text-shadow: none;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
}
```

..With this code:

```
::-moz-selection
{
    text-shadow: none;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
}
::selection {
    text-shadow: none;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
}
```

.... bingo, it works.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/GMuzV/21/)**

Support is also very good (for desktop): [Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-selection)

Also, if you use LESS or SASS - you could easily write a mixin to get around the repitition.

Comment: Surprising nobody pointed this out until now. Another thing to add is that you can remove `::-webkit-selection` entirely because it is not used by any browser.

Comment: You can also use `:active { text-shadow:none; }` which will remove the shadow as you highlight the text, onmouseup it no longer applies.

Answer (score 6):

The following [is documented on Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/::selection):

> Though this pseudo-element was in drafts of CSS Selectors Level 3, it was removed during the Candidate Recommendation phase,  as it appeared that its behavior was under-specified, especially with nested elements, and interoperability wasn't achieved (based on discussion in the W3C Style mailing list).
>
> The ::selection pseudo-element currently isn't in any CSS module on the standard track. It should not be used in production environments.

Comment: +1 thanks...so does this mean that there is no css solution for this??

Comment: AFAIK, css-only, no. And it's support ("::selection") is quite limited, too.