# CSS Grouping in Shadow Dom (progress element)

Tags: html, css, progress, shadow-dom

I can't work out for the life of me why, when you are styling the shadow DOM, you can't group the CSS rules? The problem is that The CSS rule as a whole group is discarded when you group the shadow DOM rules together. I have to lay them out like this

```
&::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: red;
}
&::-moz-progress-value {
  background: red;
}
&::-ms-progress-value {
  background: red;
}
&::progress-value {
  background: red;
}
```

Instead of something like this, for potential future proofing:

```
&::-webkit-progress-value,
&::-moz-progress-value,
&::-ms-progress-value,
&::progress-value {
  background: red;
}
```

Why is that?! Is there a better way of doing this?

Here's the codepen: http://codepen.io/marksyzm/pen/cKzjs/

Comment: I'd answer...but I don't have time this minute,

Comment: What the world needs right now are more facetious people. Here you go... edited!

Comment: Same by the ::selection property. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19075802/703717) - maybe this happens for psedo elements which have vendor prefixes?

Comment: Thanks! So there it is then. I'm guessing browsers aren't so flexible with the whole use of `::pseudo` combined with CSS then. That and... http://negativitysandwiches.com/we-need-to-have-a-talk-about-styling-html5-progress-bars-everyone/

Comment: This has nothing to do with the shadow DOM. See the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks - I up voted the answers in the original accordingly.