# CSS pseudo selection not changing text-shadow property

Tags: css, css-selectors

Whenever I use `text-shadow: none;` in `::selection`/`::-moz-selection`, it just doesn't work.

I am just confused as to why it works in websites [1](http://codepen.io/katydecorah/pen/f516263a6683d896813f6b3dea21c7c1) and [2](http://codepen.io/katydecorah/pen/5ee2c6a3e825753802755bd08fcd5c5f) but not in my code below.  [This code](http://codepen.io/katydecorah/pen/f516263a6683d896813f6b3dea21c7c1) is **exactly** what I want, but it's not working in my own code.

### My Code

```css
textarea {
  background: #778899;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px #000000;
  font-size: 50px;
}
.fortext::-moz-selection {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
  text-shadow: none;
}
.fortext::selection {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="fortext">Test</textarea>
```

[image: What I get]

Above is what I get, as you can see the shadow stays.

### What I have tried:

**text-shadow:**

- `0 0 0 #000`
- `0 0 0 none`
- `none`
- `0 0 0 clear`
- `clear`
- `0px 0px 0px none`
- `5px 5px 5px none`

None of the above code changes anything.

Also I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027452/css-to-remove-text-shadow-on-select-highlight-text-mozilla) post, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: what happens when you run it?

Comment: @hdost the shadow stays, but the background/text changes color.  I will include a picture in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome fails in the case of a textarea. It works ok for p.
That is the reason that the examples that you link are working

```css
p {
  background: #778899;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px #000000;
  font-size: 50px;
}
.fortext::-moz-selection {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
  text-shadow: none;
}
.fortext::selection {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<p class="fortext">Test</p>
```

Comment: I wonder why chrome doesn't support this and if it ever will.  Thank you though, I didn't think to test with `p`.

Comment: The reason *why*  is in the answer from Szabolks.  ... about being supported in the future, who knows ...

Answer (score 2):

`<textarea>` is a replaced element, and like many of the replaced elements, does not support certain CSS properities.

Altough I could not find it documented anywhere, but I assume you just found one.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element